# Mudar a cor de uma jProgressBar

Tags: java, progress-bar

Como posso mudar a cor a minha ProgressBar, ela fica sempre um alaranjado meio esquisito, tentei usar esse código mas não funcionou:

```
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", Color.orange);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", Color.blue);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", Color.red);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground", Color.green);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essas propriedades precisam estar definidas antes de criar o `JProgressBar`. Por exemplo:

```
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", Color.orange);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", Color.blue);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", Color.red);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground", Color.green);

JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar();
getContentPane().add(progress);
```

Se for o caso de precisar alterar a cor após o componente ter sido criado ou fazer essa mudança de cores baseando-se na porcentagem de progresso, as soluções [dessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524121/jprogressbar-how-to-change-colour-based-on-progress) <sup><sup>(en)</sup></sup> podem resolver.

Segue um exemplo, utilizando as propriedades que postou junto a pergunta. Eis o resultado:

[image: progressbar]

<sub>Coloquei em uma *thread* só para mostrar a porcentagem da barra aumentando.</sub>

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private final JProgressBar progress;

    public Window(String title) throws HeadlessException {
        super(title);
        setSize(300, 80);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", Color.orange);
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", Color.blue);
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", Color.red);
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground", Color.green);

        progress = new JProgressBar();
        progress.setStringPainted(true); // para mostrar a porcentagem como texto na barra
        getContentPane().add(progress);
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            progress.setValue(i); 
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Window("stackoverflow pt").setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Entendi, então eu estava no caminho errado pois estava usando o componente pronto. Parece ser um pouco complicado, mas vou dar uma olhada